# How to customize Chromium (Windows Platform)

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, gn

I want to modify and build the Chromium's information on Windows OS.

The application's name, author and other:

Example:

```
     Chromium -> Edge

     The Chromium Authors -> Microsoft
```

The name of file that generated by build:

Example:

```
     chrome.exe -> msedge.exe

     chrome.dll -> msedge.dll

     chrome_200_percent.pak -> msedge_2020_percent.pak
```

What should I do?